# How do I subset rows in data.table that meet some minimum criteria?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm a noob to data.table in R and I'd like to skip the last value of z=3 in this example:

```
> DT = data.table(y=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),x=1:10,z=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3))
> DT[,list(list(predict(smooth.spline(x,y),c(4,5,6))$y)),by=z]

Error in smooth.spline(x, y) : need at least four unique 'x' values
```

If I simply delete z=3 I get the answer I want:

```
> DT = data.table(y=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),x=1:8,z=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2))
> DT[,list(list(predict(smooth.spline(x,y),c(4,5,6))$y)),by=z]

   z                                                  V1
1: 1  2.09999998977689,2.49999997903384,2.89999996829078
2: 2 0.999895853971133,2.04533519691888,2.90932467439562
```

What a great package!

Comment: I think you want `as.list(predict(...`

Answer (score 3):

Omitting the rows were `z` is 3 is as simple as

```
DT[z!=3,  <whatever expression you'd like>]
```

If your data.table is keyed by `z` then you can use

```
DT[!.(3), .....]
```

Comment: How about when the subset in z must contain at least a sample size of N or greater?  (Should've been explicit about that...)  I'd like to skip a subset in z when it doesn't have sufficient sample.

Comment: Then use `ifelse` and `.N`

Comment: DT[,ifelse(.N>=4,as.list(predict(smooth.spline(x,y),c(4,5,6))$y),0),by=z]

Comment: Sorry (new to Stackflow..) but that last piece of code doesn't quite get it

Comment: Here we go:DT[,ifelse(.N>=4,list(predict(smooth.spline(x,y),c(4,5,6))$y),0),by=z]

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to omit the results when `.N <4`, then you can use `if` (not `ifelse`). If `.N <4`, then nothing is returned

```
DT[,if(.N>=4){ list(list(predict(smooth.spline(x,y),c(4,5,6))$y))},by=z]
#    z                                                  V1
# 1: 1   2.1000000266026,2.50000003412706,2.90000004165153
# 2: 2 0.999895884129996,2.04533520266699,2.90932466433092
```