# Calculate new data.table columns by row values

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large data.table of values and I need to calculate the average trip time (TRPDUR) by mode (TRANMOT) for each county area (CPA).  The output should be one table with each CPA as a row and then a column for the average time of non-motorized modes and a column for the average time for motorized modes.  I came up with a dirty way to do it in two separate data.tables:

```
mot_table <- nomot_table <- data.table(trip_dat)
mot_table <- mot_table[!is.na(TRPDUR), list("Motorized Trip Time" = mean(TRPDUR)), keyby = list(CPA, TRANMOT)][TRANMOT == "Motorized"][,TRANMOT:=NULL]
nomot_table <- nomot_table[!is.na(TRPDUR), list("Non-Motorized Trip Time" = mean(TRPDUR)), keyby = list(CPA, TRANMOT)][TRANMOT == "Non-Motorized"][,TRANMOT:=NULL]
```

That is not a beautiful way to do it and I'm sure I can do it in one table.  When I make my expression (j) a list of two columns I cannot figure out how to calculate the average only for certain values of TRANMOT.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000012/how-do-i-subset-rows-in-data-table-that-meet-some-minimum-criteria) shows how to subset the whole data.table (i) like I do by removing NAs but I want the expression to calculate an average on the subset data rather than doing the operation twice and then deleting rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us some sample data to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want...

```
trip_dat[!is.na(TRPDUR),lapply(
  c("Motorized","Non-Motorized"),
  function(x) mean(TRPDUR[TRANMOT==x])
),by='CPA']
```

It might not be fast, but something like this should work.

Comment: It works with great one weird error.  For some reason about 7 rows become NAs that didn't in my code.  I'm going to play around with this to see if I can figure out the discrepancy but lapply was definitely the right idea! Thank you.

Comment: Cool. Glad to help. I'm guessing the discrepancy comes from this: with my method, there is a by=CPA, while yours is by=CPA,TRANMOT. For mine, results are returned even for CPAs without both TRANMOT levels, while yours only returns results for observed CPA,TRANMOT pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `data.table` will soon have some reshaping functions like cast and melt.

Using `reshape2`, something like this. It doesn't use any `data.table` magic, so for very large objects this might fail. You'd have to change the column names afterwards.

```
new <- mot_table[!is.na(TRPDUR), 
          mean(TRPDUR), 
          keyby = list(CPA, TRANMOT)
         ]
new <- dcast(TRANMOT ~ CPA, data = new, value.var = V1)
```

Purely using `data.table`, maybe something like this inline. You'll have to change the column names afterwards.

```
new <- mot_table[!is.na(TRPDUR), 
          mean(TRPDUR), 
          keyby = list(CPA, TRANMOT)
         ][, setNames(lapply(unique(TRANMOT), 
                    function(x) {
                      V1[which(TRANMOT == x)]
                    }, paste0("Motorized: ", unique(TRANMOT))),
           by = CPA
          ]
```

Comment: You could use paste on the second argument of `setNames` to add the "Trip Time" bit, right?

Comment: Sure, or something like `paste0("Motorized: ", x)`. Though now I think of it `setNames` will name within the vector, instead of the list. Worth an edit...